# Can a rip on a suitcase be repaired with iron-on patches?

Tags: tips-and-tricks, damaged-luggage

While packing, I noticed a small tear (around 5`cm`) on the side of my suitcase. It's only in the outer lining, but I'm worried it could grow during (mis)handling. Getting a new one at this point would be an inconvenience. I have an [iron-on clothes patch](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51pYDrZj5wL.jpg) that's the correct size. Is it safe to apply it to the suitcase, or would the process cause more harm than good to the material? Any other ideas on how to repair it, or increase its chances of enduring one more trip?

[Here is a picture of the suitcase on Amazon](http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B001DJL1JG)

Comment: this seems like a question for lifehacks.se :)

Comment: I'm sharing the proposal to move the question to lifehack.se

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would not trust the patch alone.  The frame of the suitcase does not provide a place where you can press the iron firmly down.

To make it endure another trip, you can take two towels and lay them flat inside the *empty* suitcase so that they overlap the outsides.  Then repack all your stuff.  Valuables go into a shopping bag in the centre.

Then to close the suitcase, fold the ends of the towels over your stuff so that they 'surround' the contents.

This will distribute the stress against the tear more evenly over a wider area.  Once shut, you can use a strip of duct tape or bungee cords (or whatever's handy) to wrap around the outside of the suitcase.  This will prevent the tear from snagging on something and becoming larger.

Comment: I followed the towels tip, along with tape and a luggage belt on the outside. It looks sturdy enough

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer repair tape (easily available on Amazon or from camping supply stores) to an iron on patch. Plastic on the suitcase might melt when you use the iron. Here are some tape images:

[image: repair tape 1] 
[image: repair tape 2]

I own some of the Tenacious tape myself but have yet to use it on a suitcase. I take it on long trips and all camping trips. Reviews suggest people repair tents, coats, and sleeping bags with great success and it would seem appropriate for a suitcase also.

Comment: I ended up using a [strong type of duct tape](http://www.tesa.com/consumer/renovating_repairing/ducttapes/tesa_extra_power_extreme_outdoor,c.html). Not exactly the one pictured, but it was available at a nearby store and worked well. Thanks for dissuading me from the iron-on patch